# MissingMethodException when adding String.metaClass.call then using it on String literal

Tags: groovy, groovy-3.0

I'm trying to make `String`/`GString` objects callable with something like

```
String.metaClass.call = { println toUpperCase() + " " + it() }
```

This is producing a `MissingMethodException` when called on literals, though not always:

```
def a = 'abc'

a{ 2 * 3 }     //ABC 6                     -> OK
'a'{ 2 * 4 }   //ABC 8                     -> OK
'abc'{ 2 * 5 } //MissingMethodException    -> ERROR
```

The error is:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ConsoleScript11.abc() 
is applicable for argument types: (ConsoleScript11$_run_closure4)
```

I'll skip the fact that `'a'{ 2 * 4 }` works while `'abc'{ 2 * 5 }` doesn't. My question really is: is there a way to make invocations on literals work without Groovy trying to resolve methods with quoted identifiers?

Comment: `'abc'.call{ 3 }` works just fine, if it can save you

Comment: @injecteer Yes. But I really want to use the call operator on literals as a user feature in a dsl if that can be systematically achieved

Comment: btw I think, if you put your stuff in a proper class (not a Script), then groovy won't apply part of it's magic, and `No signature of method: ConsoleScript11.abc()` wouldn't be thrown